# Conditional probability calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given $P(B \cap A') = 0.25$, $ P(A \cap B') = 0.2$ and $P(A' \mid B') = 0.5$, how do we find $P( A \cap B)$, and $P( B' \cap A')$?

(Here $A', B'$ are the complements of $A$ and $B$ respectively)

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram. And use a formula for conditional probability.

Comment: I did and tried P(A'|B')=P(A' n B') / P(B') but I don't have sufficient info to solve it.

Comment: Sure you do. By the way, one of the things you ask for, $P(B'\cap A)$, is the same as one of the things you're given, $P(A\cap B')$.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From venn diagrams

$P(only~ B)=0.25$, $P(only~A)=0.2$, $P(\overline{A\cup B})/P(\overline{B})=0.5$

Let $P[A\cap B]= x$

$$\implies \frac{0.55-x}{0.75-x}=0.5 \implies x=0.35$$

Now you can find the rest.

Comment: P(only B) = 0.25 is wrong I guess.

Comment: No Only B means B-A$\cap$B=B$\cap$A'

Comment: B equals B - A n B ???

Comment: correct answer:  P(A n B ) = .35

Comment: @BabakKhoramdin (Only B) means B-A$\cap$B

Comment: @BabakKhoramdin Yes you are correct it's 0.35. I had placed A' instead of B'.